# reading boolean value from a file to be printed

Tags: java, readfile, numberformatexception

i'm having a trouble on my main class which is reading a boolean value from a .txt file... running my program gives me this message though compiling it doesn't give any errors

> Reading course units... 1 Reading if course is taken... false Reading
>   subject grade... 0Reading course year... 3 Reading semester... 2
>   Reading course number... IT 412a Practicum Reading descriptive
>   title... 2 Reading course units...
>   falsejava.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "false"
>
> ```
> at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
> at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
> at java.lang.Byte.parseByte(Byte.java:148)
> at java.lang.Byte.parseByte(Byte.java:174)
> at ChecklistDisplay.readChecklistInfo(ChecklistDisplay.java:74)
> at ChecklistDisplay.run(ChecklistDisplay.java:20)
> at ChecklistDisplay.main(ChecklistDisplay.java:8)
> ```

and this is an example for my .txt file

> 4,2,IT 423,Information Systems Planning/Information Resources Management,3,false,0
>   year,term,course number,units,(subject taken?),subj grade

```
System.out.println("Reading if course is taken...");
                s = lineScan.next();
                System.out.print(s);
                boolean taken = Boolean.parseBoolean(s.trim());
```

please tell me if i ever you have the need to look at my full programs for review or my question is not clear enough

Comment: Read the stack trace and check your class ChecklistDisplay, method readCheckListInfo, line 74. Here you try to parse a the string "false" as a byte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Boolean.parseBoolean` does not throw `java.lang.NumberFormatException`.

So you are probably trying to do something like `Integer.parseInt("false")` somewhere in your code and it throws the exception. Without seeing all your code it is difficult to be much more specific.

Also the output does not correspond to the sample txt extract you have shown, which does not help understanding what the issue could be.

Comment: hello, i've upload the files in a site since it'd be too long

http://speedy.sh/krT6D/checklist.rar

Comment: @user2119027 Find the line in the file which causes the exception and post that line only please. And post the rest of your code.

Comment: If you're not used to reading stack traces, the key line is: 
at ChecklistDisplay.readChecklistInfo(ChecklistDisplay.java:74). This is the line of *your* code, which is then calling some java library code which is throwing the exception.  Please post this (and the code around it)

Comment: ah yes, thank you for pointing that out assylias. i've checked my .txt file again and there were some lines that lacked some values for the parameters. it works fine now thank you again